# How can I access array's item when there is an object in it?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array like this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res_users);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [position] => 1
            [user] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [full_name] => دکوراسیون
                    [is_private] => 1
                    [has_anonymous_profile_picture] => 
                    [byline] => 39.3k followers
                    [profile_pic_url] => https://scontent-frt3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11352072_817936521647202_201395223_a.jpg
                    [pk] => 1480272396
                    [follower_count] => 39326
                    [is_verified] => 
                    [mutual_followers_count] => 0
                    [username] => sajad.sobhi
                )

        )
)
```

All I'm trying to do is selecting following URL from array above:

```
https://scontent-frt3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11352072_817936521647202_201395223_a.jpg
```

Which is the value of `profile_pic_url`. How can I get that?

---

Noted that this doesn't work:

```
echo $res_users[0]['user']['profile_pic_url'];
```

Comment: Downvoter please leave a comment and explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: `$res_users[0]->user->profile_pic_url;` Make sure you know the difference between array and object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$res_users[0]->user->profile_pic_url`. Because `$res_users[0]` is `object` type

Comment: You are right @Saumini

Comment: thank you .. upvote. Just can I convert that inner object to an array?

Comment: @stack following will convert it to array. `$user = json_decode(json_encode($res_users[0]), true);`. Then use it like `$user['user']['profile_pic_url']`

Answer (score 1):

Try it by this way
echo $res_users[0]->user->profile_pic_url;